# clear me the doubt in positioning legend option

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  samples=100,
  ymax=5,legend pos=north east
]
\addplot[cyan,domain=0.001:8] {abs(log10(x))};
\addplot[red!70!black,domain=-2:4] {2+exp(abs(x))};
\addplot[green,thick,domain=-2:3] {exp(x)};
\legend{$e^{x}$};
\node[pin={90:$f(x)=\lvert\log x\rvert$},inner sep=0pt] 
  at (axis cs:{2,log10(2)}) {};
\node[pin={0:$f(x)=e^{x}$},inner sep=0pt] 
  at (axis cs:{1,exp(1)}) {}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I used the above codes to draw three different curves in a same plane. I got it too. But for the legend:

**Question 1** I need to have only `$e^{x}$`. How I have to do this?

**Qn:2** How can I remove the framed box?

**Qn:3** I need to place my `$e^x$` in north east and `$|e^x|$` in northwest mean. How can I do this?

The diagram I got is:

[image]

(Kindly observe that the legend for `$e^x$` is giving wrong color.)

Comment: Can you please explain 3) in more detail? What is "northwest mean"?

Comment: north west I mean to place my legency in the top left corner...@GonzaloMedina

Comment: But you said "I need to place my $e^x$ in north east and $|e^x|$ in northwest mean." So, just to be clear, do you want the legend `$e^{x}$`  (with the green line) to appear in the top left corner? And, where do you want `$|e^x|$` to appear? Should it also be part of the legend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add `forget plot` to those plots that shouldn't be taken into account for the legend (the first two, in your example).
2. You can use `legend style` to customize the legend formatting; in your case, you need `draw=none` to suppress the frame.
3. Using the various coordinate systems provided by pgfplots, you can place elements at any desired location. In the example below I used the axis description system to add `\lervt e^{x}\rvert`.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  samples=100,
  ymax=5,legend pos=north east,
  legend style={draw=none}
]
\addplot[forget plot,cyan,domain=0.001:8] {abs(log10(x))};
\addplot[forget plot,red!70!black,domain=-2:4] {2+exp(abs(x))};
\addplot[green,thick,domain=-2:3] {exp(x)};
\addlegendentry{$e^{x}$};
\node[pin={90:$f(x)=\lvert\log x\rvert$},inner sep=0pt] 
  at (axis cs:{2,log10(2)}) {};
\node[pin={0:$f(x)=e^{x}$},inner sep=0pt] 
  at (axis cs:{1,exp(1)}) {};
\node[anchor=north west] 
  at (axis description cs:0,0.5)
  {$\lvert e^{x}\rvert$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]